# replace pattern in file 2 with pattern in file 1 if contingency is met

Tags: linux, if-statement, awk, sed

I have two tab delimted data files the file1 looks like:

```
cluster_j_72    cluster-32  cluster-32  cluster_j_72
cluster_j_75    cluster-33  cluster-33  cluster_j_73
cluster_j_8 cluster-68  cluster-68  cluster_j_8
```

the file2 looks like:

```
   NODE_148        67545   97045   cluster-32
   NODE_221        1       42205   cluster-33
   NODE_168        1       24506   cluster-68
```

I would like to confirm that, for a given row, in file1 columns 2 and 3; as well as 1 and 4 are identical. If this is the case then I would like to take the value for that row from column 2 (file 1) find it in file2 and replace it with the value from column 1 (file 1). Thus the new output of file 2 would look like this (note because column 1 and 4 dont match for cluster 33 (file1) the pattern is not replaced in file2):

```
   NODE_148        67545   97045   cluster_j_72  
   NODE_221        1       42205   cluster-33  
   NODE_168        1       24506   cluster_j_8
```

I have been able to get the contingency correct (here printing the value from file1 i'd like to use to replace a value in file2):

```
    awk '{if($2==$3 && $1==$4){print $1}}'file1
```

If I could get sed to draw values ($2 and $1) from file1 while looking in file 2 this would work:

```
     sed 's/$2(from file1)/$1(from file1)/' file2
```

But I don't seem to be able to nest this sed in the previous awk statement, nor get sed to look for a pattern originating in a different file than it's looking in.

thanks!

Comment: See `man join`. You can join both files using the columns the have in common and output the format with the desired columns in desired order. Then if you need more manipulation you can use sed or awk in that joined file, it will be much easier.

Comment: Replace the word `pattern` with either `string` or `regexp` everywhere it occurs in your question so we know what kind of matching you're looking for. (patterns are for quilts and knitting, not for software!). Also, if file2 doesn't REALLY start with white space then fix your example. Ditto for the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never need sed when you're using awk since awk can do anything that sed can do.

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    if ( ($1 == $4) && ($2 == $3) ) {
        map[$2] = $1
    }
    next
}
$4 in map { $4 = map[$4] }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
NODE_148        67545   97045   cluster_j_72
NODE_221        1       42205   cluster-33
NODE_168        1       24506   cluster_j_8
```

Comment: Hi Ed -- Thanks for the reply. I'm a bit of a neophyte with all this. Could you tell me me how to implement the code you provided above? It doesn't seem to be a bash script and it doesn't seem to just be a command line i could enter.

Comment: Create a file named `tst.awk` with the content shown above (the output of `cat tst.awk` in my answer) and then run `awk` on it as shown above and against your 2 input files: `awk -f tst.awk file1 file2`.

Comment: I got your code above to run, but it didn't replace any of the cluster names. Perhaps this has to do with the fact that the output of file 1 is not the same length or order to the cluster names in file2? is there anyway around that?

Comment: As you can see in my answer when you run it against the sample input files you provided it produces the output you provided. Is that not what you get when you run it against those files? if not, what DO you get? if you're running it against some other files and not getting the expected output then figure out whats different about your current input from the sample you provided and then fix your question to provide a more truly representative example.

Comment: I apologize: I had used the wrong file before. Your solution works -- thank you!